# Syllable count in a line of Rosemonde Gérard

Tags: poésie

The [Wikipedia edition](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99%C3%89ternelle_chanson) of *L'éternelle chanson* (a poem written by [Rosemonde Gérard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemonde_G%C3%A9rard)) seems incorrect :

> Lorsque tu seras vieux et que je serai vieille,
>   Lorsque mes cheveux blonds seront des cheveux blancs,
>   Au mois de mai, dans le jardin qui s’ensoleille,
>   Nous irons réchauffer nos vieux membres tremblants.
>   Comme le renouveau mettra nos cœurs en fête,
>   Nous nous croirons encore de jeunes amoureux,

The sixth line is problematic : it can't be an [alexandrin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrin) since it's made of 13 syllables :

> Nous(1) nous(2) croi(3)rons(4) en(5)co(6)re(7) de(8) jeu(9)nes(10) a(11)mou(12)reux(13),

Is this line correctly written ? I beg we should read :

> Nous nous croirons encor de jeunes amoureux,

... *encor* being an alternative spelling for *encore*; moreover, with *encor* we could have the [hémistiche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9mistiche) exactly after the sixth syllable, as expected.

May someone check the exact spelling in any paper edition ? I can't check it by myself.

Any help would be appreciated !

---

By the way, there is(?) another error in the wikipedia edition of this poem. See at the end the famous lines :

> Et comme chaque jour je t’aime davantage,
>   Aujourd’hui plus qu’hier et bien moins que demain,
>   Qu’importeront alors les rides du visage ?
>   Mon amour se fera plus grave ― et serein.

The last line I quote should be read :

> Mon amour se fera plus grave et plus serein.

That's the way I learned these lines fifteen years ago.

Comment: Not paper, but the [edition](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=KP6RAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22Nous+nous+croirons+encor+de+jeunes+amoureux%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22amour+se+fera+plus+grave%22) reproduced therein complies exactly with your recollection. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always thought that "encor" was used only in 17th or 18th century poetry. But https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encor cites a Boris Vian poem from the 1950's. So it seems right to replace the "encore" in the Rosemonde Gérard poem by "encor".

Answer (score 0):

In standard French, the last e is mute so *encore* is made up of two syllables and is exactly pronounced like *encor* which would have been indeed a better alternative here, being precisely an invention (*license poétique*) to align the pronunciation with the classical poetry rules.

I guess either the original text was later "hyper-corrected" or the *hémistiche* following *encore* was enough for the author to assert the "e" was kept mute, like it is at the end of a verse.

Comment: I beg to disagree : the last "e" in "encore de" is a "e muet" before a consonant; therefore, in French poetry, it cannot be dismissed.

Comment: The mute *e* cannot indeed be dismissed before a consonant but a *e caduc* before the *hémistiche* is nevertheless strictly forbidden. This verse is then "impossible" according the the classical rules and then the logic impose pronouncing it like if *encor* was used.